# Accessing fields of derived classes from a List of a base class

Tags: c#, list, inheritance, syntax, polymorphism

I'm using C# and XNA 4.0, as well as Farseer Physics Engine (very similar to Box2D), and have a Block class from which I derive OBlock, LBlock, etc.

Block is as follows:

```
class Block
{
    public Body m_body;
    public virtual void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch) { }

    public virtual void RemoveBody(World world)
    {
        //world.RemoveBody(m_body);
    }
}
```

I've only put those methods, fields, etc in so I can access their overridden versions in a List

So my overridden versions look something like this:
OBlock.cs

```
class OBlock : Block
{

    private static Texture2D blockImg; //I load this in LoadContent so I don't have loads of Texture2Ds
    public new Body m_body; //Is this right?

    public OBlock(World world, Vector2 position)
    {
        m_body = BodyFactory.CreateBody(world, position); // Create the body, changing it from null
        FixtureFactory.AttachRectangle(Game1.blockSide *2, Game1.blockSide *2, 1.0f, new Vector2(0, 0), m_body); //This bit changes between classes
        m_body.BodyType = BodyType.Dynamic;

    }

    public override void RemoveBody(World world)
    {
        world.RemoveBody(m_body);
    }

    public static void LoadImage(Texture2D tex)
    {
        OBlock.blockImg = tex;
    }

    public override void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {

        Vector2 position = m_body.Position * Game1.MetreInPixels;
        Vector2 origin = new Vector2(blockImg.Width / 2, blockImg.Height / 2);

        float rotation = m_body.Rotation;

        spriteBatch.Begin();

        spriteBatch.Draw(blockImg, position, null, Color.White, rotation, origin, Game1.BLOCK_SCALE, SpriteEffects.None, 1);

        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(spriteBatch);
    }
}
```

There's also LBlock, ZBlock, etc which all look very similar apart from the bit I commented.

I then have them all in

```
List<Block> blocks //As a field in Game1

blocks = new List<Block>(); // In LoadContent after loading images
```

What I'm trying to do is access m_body for any Block in the list regardless of type using

```
blocks[index].m_body.DOSTUFF();
```

Apparently m_body is always null...

Comment: What happens when you step through the code one line at a line, watching m_body on the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public new Body m_body;
```

This is not right. The `m_body` from your `Block` class (which you should mark `abstract` btw) is visible in all classes deriving from it. What you're doing right now is called hiding (which should always be avoided  imo), which causes various complications.

You've now made it so that each `OBlock` has two members `m_body`, one belonging to `Block`, one belonging to `OBlock`. It makes it so that any time you reference `this.m_body` in your `OBlock` class, you're assigning the `m_body` field belonging to `OBlock`, leaving `m_block` declared in `Block` alone. This is one of the weird complication that comes with hiding members:

```
Block myBlock = new OBlock();
// myBlock.m_block is null, because myBlock is of type block, and remember,
// the m_block belonging to Block is never assigned to, only the one belonging
// to OBlock
```

Whereas this would work as expected:

```
OBlock myOBlock = new OBlock();
// myOBlock.m_block isn't null, because it was assigned to in the constructor.
```

So avoid hiding! Remove

```
public new Body m_body;
```

from your code file and you're good to go, because `m_block` declared in `Block` is inherited by all classes deriving from it anyway.

Comment: The thing is, I want to have a List of all my different blocks which I can step though, and access the bodies of any block I want. Am I right that this requires a List of the base class to step through, which I then put derived classes in?

Comment: @WilliamOsborne You loop through the list and instantiate each one of them with a derived class yes. If you remove the `public new Body m_body;` line from your code, everything should be fine, and will work as you described.

Answer (score 2):

public new Body m_body; //Is this right?

No! this declares a second bit of storage - so you have Block's m_body and OBlock's m_body and you only initialize one to be non-null. The exact rules for what a particular reference to m_body will resolve to are probably too boring to want to understand.

You should probably remove the line above completely and spend some time getting comfortable with the basics of inheritance e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173149.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
public new Body m_body;
```

This hides m_body of the base class. So basically you are defining a new instance of m_body in derived class (not of base class). So I assume that's the reason your m_body of base class would be null because it is never initialized.

So instead remove that particular line because for every derived classes, m_body is already defined as all are derived from Block class. Go through [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#vclrfnew_newmodifier) for more details.